# How to get string value from mfc popupmenu when clicked without making use of resource id

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cmenu

I'm creating a dynamic popup menu without generating resource ids. How can I keep track of the clicked action without a resource id?

Is there any way I can get menu's string value?

```
CMenu m_subMenu;
m_subMenu.CreatePopupMenu();

utf16string actionName(L"");
int nCatgryId = 1000;

for( ; itr != itrEnd ; ++itr)
{
    actionName     = itr->first;
    CString csActionName = actionName.c_str();
    AppendMenu(MF_STRING,nId++, csActionName);
}
```

So how do I obtain the value from the menu when an action is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

```
#define YOURMENU_ID  WM_APP+10
...
AppendMenu(.., YOURMENU_ID,...);
```

And handle it in `WM_COMMAND`

Comment: thanks ajay for the reply   but i need to get the menu name when right clicked without making use of id

Comment: getmenustring needs id to be passed

Comment: You don't want any id, but you want information for a menu item? How's that possible?
I didn't ask you to use resource, but a locally defined macro.

Comment: im creating a dynamic menu so my id cant be defined as a macro

Answer (score 0):

Every menu item, when you create it, needs to have an ID. You need to reserve a list of ID's, use those to create the menu items, then use the normal menu functions to get information on them.